# Should I remove a wrong answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I posted a slightly wrong answer to a question.

In time the user received the correct answer and my answer was voted down - so far, so fine.

Now I'm wondering if I should remove my wrong answer (since editing would be misleading, because then there would be a correct, but down voted answer)?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, so a comment instead: If you feel your edit would either add nothing to what the current, correct answer says or you feel you couldn't edit your answer to be correct, there is no harm in deleting your answer. If you think you can edit your answer to be correct without just repeating what the other answer says or pointing to the other answer, feel free to edit! Others can see your edited answer and vote accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should edit your answer to be a correct, quality, answer, if you can.  Your assertion that you shouldn't fix your answer is incorrect.

You should only delete the answer if you can't fix it into a useful answer.